# Create a table from another via SQL query in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

As I learn SQL, I am trying to create a table called `Dummy_Table` from another table, `Contacts`, using a `SQL query` in MS-Access. But, the code below keeps giving me a `syntax error`.

How can I fix it?

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Dummy_Table
AS
SELECT ID, Company
FROM Contacts;
```

Data:

```
ID  Company                 Name
5   ADEPT Leadership        A
10  Automation Anywhere     M
11  Automation Anywhere     G
20  Cisco Systems, Inc.     P
23  Descartes Labs, Inc.    P
24  Descartes Labs, Inc.    P
18  Gartner                 R
1   Google                  H
2   Google                  M
19  Microsoft               V
15  Pitney Bowes            S
25  Pitney Bowes            T
9   Pitney Bowes            S
13  Remix                   G
6   Splunk Inc.             W
8   Splunk Inc.             K
16  Tectonix Federal, LLC   B
22  Tectonix Federal, LLC   M
3   Tectonix Federal, LLC   G
7   Tectonix Federal, LLC   W
14  Tectonix Federal, LLC   J
17  Teralytics              M
21  Xmode Social            I
4   Xmode Social            S
```

Comment: You are trying to perform a `select into`. Its been a  minute with msaccess for me but I think just `select ID, Company into Dummy_Table from Contacts`. Access also calls this a "make table query"

Comment: oh okay so I am using the wrong code then, as all I want to do is to get the first two columns from `Contacts` and put them in a new table `Dummy_Table`.

Comment: Oh I see so MS-Access SQL does not include the `CREATE TABLE` statement/function.

Comment: It does but that's not how create table works anyway. Its a little less common in MSAccess to use raw sql to create tables - basically its not entirely up to snuff (to my mind - the datatypes are a little wonky, and there is weird stuff about compression). Better to use the table designer. If you did want to use create table, you create the table first .... then you insert into it.

Comment: Now I am getting `The action or event has been blocked by Disabled Mode` when I run `SELECT ID, Company INTO Dummy_Table FROM Contacts`

Comment: that's a new one. Try this ? [stop-disabled-mode-from-blocking-a-query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/stop-disabled-mode-from-blocking-a-query-0171e2dd-f9b0-4ffa-a542-2278ce1babb1)

Comment: Why do you need to create table and not just use SELECT query? Just to learn, not for any practical need?

Comment: Yep, just to learn.